# How can I automatically produce one deployment directory from multiple projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

I have several C# console projects in my solution where each project refers to external DLLs or local images. I want to produce a clean directory for deployment which contains, for example,

> ConsoleApplication1.exe
>
> ConsoleApplication1-resource1.jpg
>
> ConsoleApplication1-resource2.jpg
>
> ConsoleApplication2.exe
>
> ConsoleApplication3.exe
>
> ConsoleApplication4.exe
>
> ConsoleApplication4-resource1.jpg
>
> ConsoleApplication4-libarary.dll
>
> Common-library-for-all-projects.dll

without PDB or manifest files.

I could modify all project settings so that all **Output path** parameters point to the same directory. However, I need to modify a bunch of project settings and I guess there should be a reason for not sharing the same output directory across the projects.

I also have tried `Publish...` command but I couldn't publish all projects in my solution **at once** and this produced unnecessary setup files.

How should I setup my Visual Studio solution/project settings to automatically produce one distributable directory from multiple projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the solution (or any specific projects) from the commandline using MSBuild and provide the OutputPath as a property, which would override the values configured in each project.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /p:OutputPath="c:\foo"
```